# WSO2 OAuth2: How to logout with AppAuth iOS

Tags: ios, wso2, logout, openid-connect

I am using AppAuth-iOS Library https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS for authorization via WSO2 server. I've tried to do revoke token but that is not do anything, with the same android library revoke just do the job. How I need to properly logout user?

I've tried to:

- To clear cookie commonAuthId but I cannot even list that cookie programmatically
- To follow this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/32351144/978352 and enter similar like this https://localhost:9443/commonauth?commonAuthLogout=true&type=oidc&commonAuthCallerPath=http://localhost:8080/openidconnect/oauth2client&relyingParty=OpenidConnectWebapp and it works when I try with nodejs app but with AppAuth-iOS Library is not working and do nothing when executed.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to do revoke token but that is not do anything

Yes, this is true. Access token revoking and sign-off from OAuth2 authorization server are two different things.The main usage of revoking access token after issuing an access token: a user or an admin can revoke it in case of theft or a security violation. More information can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Token+API#TokenAPI-Renewingaccesstokens).

So in order to terminate the SSO session in WSO2IS, [there is a custom way this can be achieved](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/01/08/openid-connect-identity-server/) which you already have tested. Since you also noticed that this worked with Node.js OAuth2 client app, there should be something wrong with AppAuth-iOS OAuth2 client. So it would be better to debug AppAuth-iOS client application so as to find root cause of this.

[OpenID Connect Session Management Support](http://malithiedirisinghe.blogspot.com/2016/03/openid-connect-session-management.html) comes with WSO2 IS 5.2.0 onwards. You may [try it out](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/). This is the proper way to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a pending [pull request](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/pull/259) with [dev-logout](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/tree/dev-logout) branch that is still WIP.